# What can I use to retrieve a CSV file from a URL and make it an InputStream?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring Web MVC project and I have a requirement where I need to hit a URL and retrieve the CSV from it.

When I manually hit the URL, it prompts me to download the CSV to a file. I've been told this is just because of the browser.

I've also been advised to use Apache HTTP Components...

So I have this right now

```
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials( 
                new AuthScope(URL, PORTNUM),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
            AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
            BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
            authCache.put( new HttpHost( URL, PORTNUM), basicAuth);
            BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            localContext.setAttribute( ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

I've also been trying to follow another project my company has done to authenticate against the page, but it is slightly different. 
This isn't providing me the results I need (of course...) since it is incomplete.

I need to return the response into an InputStream...

Maybe I am completely wrong about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpEntity` provides the method [`getContent()`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent%28%29) which returns an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html?is-external=true).

You can use

```
InputStream is = entity.getContent()
```

and continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

`ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity));`

Using `EntityUtils` you can transform the entity to byte array and then create `ByteArrayInputStream` which inherits `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just add

```
InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
```

to what you have?